# Conditional attr_readonly in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have created a customer details form that has fields for Surname and Gender.

Since a Customer's Surname can change if they are Female, I would like to have the Surname field as a protected attribute only if gender is male.

My Customer Model looks like follows:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
    enum gender: { male:   0, female:  1 }
    attr_readonly       :last_name, :if => :male?
```

I would expect the above to work but it doesn't? Any ideas?

Comment: "A Customer's Surname can [only] change if they are Female." In what country?

Comment: You probably want to use a custom validation to do what you want. I couldn't find anything that supports a conditional attr_readonly.

Comment: I have plenty of friends who have taken their wives' last names. That said, you can use a before save callback with dirty tracking to check and revert the attr to its old value if it has changed and the customer is a male.

Comment: Okay. You guys have made me change my mind on this feature. Thanks a lot for the advice! In general, I still think that Conditional attr_readonly should be a built in feature.